# How i can redirect to another page with data in sveltekit?

Tags: redirect, prisma, sveltekit

Iam making an attendance web app with sveltekit and in class managment page, I have list of classes and i want to go to another page to add/edit/delete students to a selected class
note: im using prisma sqlite as my database.

can any one tell me if there is a way to redirect from the groups page to student page with the ID of that group as Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One would usually just use [route parameters](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing) for that, they will be available in [`load`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-js) as part of the event object and on the page they will be available as part of the [page store](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#public-types-page).

No need to get `data` involved, just insert the ID into the URL on redirect.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did after a bit of research, thx for helping